# vercel response time longer then 60sec how can I solve it?

Tags: next.js, vercel

I have a function that creates a lot of pds and created then a zip where all pdfs are in there. Until its finish it takes 3minutes. In vercel you have 60seconds time for serverless functions so a solution where to use a enterprise packet but thats tooo expensive. How can I solve this issue ?

func example:

```
...
      let stream2 = await renderToStream(<PDF_BUCHUNGS {...d} />)

      let body2: Buffer = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let buffers: Uint8Array[] = [];
        stream2.on("data", (data) => {
          buffers.push(data);
        });
        stream2.on("end", () => {
          resolve(Buffer.concat(buffers));
          bf.push({buffer: Buffer.concat(buffers), topic: 'BUCHUNGSBESTÄTIGUNG'});
        });
        stream2.on("error", reject);
      });

    }

    const r = ZipFile(bf);

    let headers = new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream", "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=ttt.zip", "Content-Length": r.length.toString() });
    return new Response(r, { status: 200, headers });
```

Comment: A solution would be to host the frontend on Vercel, and use a serverful API for the heavy work. You can try Railway or fly.io, for example.